# How to send UDP packet from C# API through Azure VPN Tunnel

Tags: azure, web-services, udp, iot

I've got an API in azure as a web service and in some instances I need to be able to fire off a UDP packet to some IoT devices that are behind a VPN.  I've configured a VPN connection, gateway, etc in Azure successfully.  What I'm not clear on is how to direct the outgoing UDP message from my web service through that VPN.  Is this supposed to just work?  Or is there some configuration step I'm missing for connecting the web service into the VPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already configured VPN for your Virtual Network, the next step would be [App Service VNet integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) to access your resources in VNet from App Service.

> The VNet Integration feature enables your apps to access resources in or through a VNet.

and

> The VNet Integration features:
>
> - Require a Standard, Premium, PremiumV2, or Elastic Premium pricing plan.
> - Support TCP and **UDP**.
> - Work with Azure App Service apps and    function apps.

and also

> Gateway-required VNet Integration provides access to resources only in
> the target VNet or in networks connected to the target VNet with
> peering or VPNs.

it should cover your needs, you can find a tutorial in [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#enable-vnet-integration).